# Mahapp ShowMessageAsync MvvM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mahapps.metro

I created the simplest WPF project with a MVVM pattern. How can I call `ShowMessageAsync` from my viewModel?

```
 if (DisciplineText!="")
 {
     Disciplines.Add(new Discipline(){ChairID = SelectedChair.ChairID,SemesterID = SelectedSemester.SemesterID,Discipline1 = DisciplineText});
     Context.SaveChanges();
 }
 else
 {
     //  ShowMessageAsync????????
 }
```

Answer (score 7):

```
MetroWindow metroWindow = Application.Current.MainWindow as MetroWindow;
metroWindow.MetroDialogOptions.ColorScheme = MetroDialogColorScheme.Accented; // set the theme
await MetroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Title", "Message");
```

You need to use :

```
using MahApps.Metro.Controls;
using MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;
```

I hope it help :)

Comment: Then you've added a dependency on the window to the view-model though.

Comment: @Cedric is right -- Just set up a messaging service in your MainWindow... then you can send messages to it from your viewmodel. The viewmodel shouldn't care about `Application.Current.MainWindow`

Comment: When I changed your last line to `await metroWindow.ShowMessageAsync("Title", "Message");`(calling object not the class) worked for me.

Answer (score 7):

One mechanism for handling these has [been added](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/pull/1943) since the question was originally asked through what it calls a `DialogCoordinator`. [This blog post](https://dragablz.net/2015/05/29/using-mahapps-dialog-boxes-in-a-mvvm-setup/) by the author contains a description on how to use it; in case that disappears, the main steps are the following:

Add the following to the xaml of the view:

```
xmlns:Dialog="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls.Dialogs;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
Dialog:DialogParticipation.Register="{Binding}"
```

Inject the `DialogCoordinator` into your view-model in whichever way is relevant for your application:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new MainWindowViewModel(DialogCoordinator.Instance);
}
```

Start showing some dialogs:

```
public MainWindowViewModel(IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator)
{
    this.dialogCoordinator = dialogCoordinator;    
}

private IDialogCoordinator dialogCoordinator;

private void ShowDialog()
{
    dialogCoordinator.ShowMessageAsync(this, "Title of dialog", "Message in dialog");
}
```

Comment: This should have been marked as the correct answer.