# How to access ShowMessageAsync method of MetroWindow from ViewModel

Tags: wpf, mvvm, viewmodel, mahapps.metro

I am using MahApps.metro WPF library with MVVM. I have a ViewModel from which I need to display a Dialog. The MetroWindow has ShowMessageAsync. But what is the proper way to access it from the ViewModel? As I understand I need a View instance but passing that into the ViewModel doesn't seem like a good approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mahapp ShowMessageAsync MvvM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825250/mahapp-showmessageasync-mvvm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use following approach:

1. Take an `Action<T>` `ShowMessageAsync` in your `ViewModel` which you are binding with window.
2. Now create a behaviour for Window and use following code in behaviour

   ```
   protected override void OnAttached()
   {
       base.OnAttached();
       this.AssociatedObject.Loaded += AssociatedObject_Loaded;
   }

   void AssociatedObject_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
       if (this.AssociatedObject.DataContext is WindowViewModel)
       {
           WindowViewModel vm = this.AssociatedObject.DataContext as WindowViewModel;

           vm.ShowMessageAsync = OnShowMessageAsync;
       }
   }

   private void OnShowMessageAsync(T param)
   { 
            //Write your logic to call ShowMessageAsync method.
   }
   ```

Now in this way, from the `ViewModel` of your `MainWindow` you will have ability to open another child window.